# Can't fire action on dynamically created elements with Jquery .on

Tags: jquery, bind, live

As many users, I can't seem to bind/fire action to dynamically created elements.

With my existing elements, the function is running, with dynamic ones, when my link is clicked, the url is loaded. (url is not important, it's for my test before other actions to be written)

What am I missing ?
I'm using jQuery 1.7.1

Thank you!!

```
jQuery('.image-widget-data').append('<a href="http://www.google.com">Select Files</a>');

jQuery("body").on("click", ".image-widget-data a", function(){ 
   event.preventDefault();             
   alert("Goodbye!"); 
});
```

Comment: Should work fine if you put `event` as handler argument: http://jsfiddle.net/meA3Q/.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing the `event` declaration in your click handler function.

```
jQuery("body").on("click", ".image-widget-data a", function(event){ 
                                                            ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(".image-widget-data").on("click", "a", function( event ){ 
   event.preventDefault();             
   alert("Goodbye!"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to pass event as param

```
jQuery("body").on("click", ".image-widget-data a", function(event){ 
   event.preventDefault();             
   alert("Goodbye!"); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fbaWW/

Comment: Arffff! Must stop to party ;)